# Xymatrix. ArchArrow

Tags: arrows, xymatrix

I have a trouble with this code:

```
\xymatrix(\boxed{1.}\ar@2{<->}[r]&\boxed{2.}\ar@2{<->}[r]&\boxed{3.}\ar@2{<->}[r]&\boxed{4.}\ar@2{<->}[r]&\boxed{5.}}
```

I'd like to get an Arch-Arrow of the same type of \ar@2{<->}[r] that bonds \boxed{1.} to \boxed{5.}. How Must I do?
Please Help Me, Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be easier to help if your example is compilable.  Please extend it to start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Bend and shift the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
  \fbox{1.} \ar@2{<->}[r] &
  \fbox{2.} \ar@2{<->}[r] &
  \fbox{3.} \ar@2{<->}[r] &
  \fbox{4.} \ar@2{<->}[r] &
  \fbox{5.} \ar@2 @<-0.5ex> @/_1.5pc/ @{<->}[llll]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, semantically, `\fbox` is better than `\boxed`. On the other hand, while the bent arrow might be good when explaining on the blackboard, I feel it useless on a printed document.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm writing a Treatise of ALGEBRA. Thx again